# EF Core : how to Insert data releated tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm new to Entity Framework Core and learning.

I have a question: I have three tables with many-to-many relations (Product, ProductCategory, Categories). Everything works fine, I can update, delete and add database.

But I couldn't add `Product` data to related tables. It just inserts into the `Product` table, but I want to add Id data to `ProductCategories`.

Thank you for helping me here.

This is my code:

Generic repository

```
public class EfCoreGenericRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
        where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    public virtual void Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        using (var context = new TContext())
        {
            context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        using (var context = new TContext())
        {
            context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public List<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        using (var context = new TContext())
        {
            return context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        }
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new TContext())
        {
            return context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        using (var context = new TContext())
        {
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

ProductRepository

```
public class EfCoreProductRepository : EfCoreGenericRepository<Product, FoodContext>, IProductRepository
{
    public Product GetByIdWithCategories(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new FoodContext())
        {
            return context.Products
                          .Where(p => p.ProductId == id)
                          .Include(p => p.ProductCategories)
                          .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Category)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public List<Product> GetProductsByCategory(string name)
    {
        using (var context = new FoodContext())
        {
            var products = context.Products.AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                products = products.Include(i => i.ProductCategories)
                                   .ThenInclude(i => i.Category)
                                   .Where(i => i.ProductCategories.Any(a => a.Category.Name.ToLower() == name.ToLower()));
            }

            return products.ToList();
        }
    }
        
    public void Update(Product entity, int[] categoryIds)
    {
        using (var context = new FoodContext())
        {
            var product = context.Products
                                 .Include(i => i.ProductCategories)
                                 .FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProductId == entity.ProductId);

            if (product != null)
            {
                product.Name = entity.Name;
                product.Price = entity.Price;
                product.ImageUrl = entity.ImageUrl;

                product.ProductCategories = categoryIds.Select(catid => new ProductCategory() {
                        ProductId = entity.ProductId,
                        CategoryId = catid
                    }).ToList();
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    
    // I may override Create code here.
}
```

MVC Post method

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProduct(ProductModel model, IFormFile file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            var randomName = string.Format($"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}{extension}");

            model.ImageUrl = randomName;

            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\img\\Products", randomName);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }

        var entity = new Product()
                {
                    Name = model.Name,
                    Price = model.Price,
                    ImageUrl = model.ImageUrl,
                    CategoryId = model.CategoryId
                };

        if (_productService.Create(entity))
        {
            TempData.Put("message", new AlertMessage
                    {
                        Title = $"{entity.Name} named product added successfully",
                        Message = $"{entity.Name} named product added successfully",
                        AlertType = "alert-success"
                    });
            return RedirectToAction("ProductList");
        };

        TempData.Put("message", new AlertMessage
                {
                    Title = _productService.ErrorMessage,
                    Message = _productService.ErrorMessage,

                });
    }

    ViewBag.Categories = _categoryService.GetAll();
    return View(model);
}
```

You can ask for more code if you need to see it. Thanks for now!

Edit ---> Entity Classes

Category.cs

```
public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories{get; set;}
    }
```

Product.cs

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double? Price { get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        
        public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories{get; set;}
    }
```

ProductCategories.cs

```
public class ProductCategory
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product{get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your Entity classes to the question?  Are you sure that model.CategoryId is not null?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I added entity classes too. CategoryId is null because I wanted to control it with error messages manually.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Why do you have public int? CategoryId in Product class?  ProductCategory should be managing your relationship between Product and Category.

Comment: You had said many to many.  Is that true?  Can a Product really be in multiple Categories?  I can understand a Category having many Products, but not necessarily the other way round.

Comment: if product has multiple categories then what is the purpose of `int? CategoryId` in `Product` class?

Comment: @memo1093 I don't see a code where it is trying to insert a record in `ProductCategory`. Assigning `Product.CategoryId = model.CategoryId` wouldn't magically add a record in `ProductCategory`. After adding a product `_productService.Create(entity)`, you should be able to get the id of newly inserted record from `entity` variable and then issue another database operation for `ProductCategory` record. As a side note, there is no need for `CategoryId` in product since there is many to many relation.

Comment: I can reach entity category id but i can't insert it to ProductCategory how i can do that i don't know.

Comment: I did it thanks to you! I inserted data with  base.Create(entity); and then I wrote another using sequence. I don't know how true but i'll share the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Pirate. I solved problem. I'm new in efcore but i was aware of many to many relationship unnecessary. I had done for many products with many categories but I changed my mind later. Maybe I can use it for next codes.

```
public override void Create(Product entity)
        {
            base.Create(entity);
            using (var context = new FoodContext())
            {
                var product = context.Products
                                        .Where(i=>i.ProductId==entity.ProductId)
             

                       .Include(i=>i.ProductCategories).FirstOrDefault();
            
                product.ProductCategories.Add(new ProductCategory(){
                    ProductId=entity.ProductId,
                    CategoryId=(int)entity.CategoryId
                });
            
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Note: I don't know how true using double using-code-block